# Phalcon validate field if exist post data

Tags: validation, phalcon

I've notice that phalcon validation model will do validation no matter the field do exist in post.

```
public function validation()
{
    $this->validate(new Uniqueness(
        array(
            "field"   => "email",
            "message" => "The email is already registered"
        )
    ));
    $this->validate(new Email(
        array(
            "field"   => "companyEmail",
            "message" => "Email format error"
        )
    ));
    return $this->validationHasFailed() != true;
}
```

In this case even if the user is saving other data rather than email, the email field still being verified. How to make it validate only if the field exist? ( for some field its really not needed to validate everytime )

maybe something like

```
if( *syntax* ){
    $this->validate(new Email(
        array(
            "field"   => "companyEmail",
            "message" => "Email format error"
        )
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here my solution:

```
if( !empty($this-companyEmail) ){
    $this->validate(new Email(
        array(
            "field"   => "companyEmail",
            "message" => "Email format error"
        )
    ));
}
```

I'm doing this as I am passing the variable via ajax

Answer (score 2):

Use a form class (subclass of Phalcon\Forms\Form), add code to check for the existence of the variable in your beforeValidate function and only add the validator if the variable is set.

```
function beforeValidation($data, $entity) 
{
  ...
  $elements = $this->getElements();

  if (isset($data['fieldname'])) {
     $elements['fieldname']->addValidator(new Email(
        array(
            "field"   => "companyEmail",
            "message" => "Email format error"
        )
    ))
     ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my implementation for Phalcon 3.4

```
class SometimesOf extends \Phalcon\Validation\Validator\PresenceOf
{

    public function __construct(array $options = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($options);
        $this->setOption('allowEmpty', true);
        
        if(!$this->hasOption('message')){
            $this->setOption('message', 'Field :field cannot be empty');
        }
    }

    public function isAllowEmpty(Validation $validator, $field)
    {
        $keys = array_keys($validator->getData());
        return !in_array($field, $keys, true);
    }

}
```

And in the validator use it as a...

```
$validation->add('foo', new PresenceOf());

$validation->add('bar', new SometimesOf());

$messages = $validation->validate($data);
```